# How to load argparse from Namespace string?

Tags: python, argparse

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(fromfile_prefix_chars='@')
parser.add_argument('--a', default=1)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

then I store args into file:

```
with open('/tmp/a', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(args))
```

what in the file is just like that:

```
Namespace(a='2')
```

So, how can I load this string into args ?

Comment: There isn't a convenient way of doing that.  The dictionary produced by `vars(args)` would be easier to save and reload.  `pickle` is one way.  To save a readable form you would try `JSON` format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  1 import argparse
  2 from argparse import Namespace
  3 
  4 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  5 parser.add_argument('--a', default=1)
  6 args = parser.parse_args()
  7 
  8 import os
  9 if os.path.exists('/tmp/a'):
 10     with open('/tmp/a', 'r') as f:
 11         ns = f.read()
 12         print(ns)
 13         args = parser.parse_args(namespace=eval(ns))
 14 else:
 15     with open('/tmp/a', 'w') as f:
 16         f.write(str(args))
 17         
 18 print(args.a)
```

since string `Namespace(a='2')` comes from a Namespace instance, so we can eval it.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested it - `pickle` works with an `argparse.Namespace` object:

```
In [727]: import pickle
In [728]: pickle.dumps(argparse.Namespace(a=10))
Out[728]: b'\x80\x03cargparse\nNamespace\nq\x00)\x81q\x01}q\x02X\x01\x00\x00\x00aq\x03K\nsb.'
In [729]: pickle.loads(_)
Out[729]: Namespace(a=10)
```

This requires an imported `argparse`.

and the dictionary pickle that I suggested in the comment:

```
In [730]: pickle.dumps(vars(_))
Out[730]: b'\x80\x03}q\x00X\x01\x00\x00\x00aq\x01K\ns.'
In [731]: pickle.loads(_)
Out[731]: {'a': 10}
```